# How to use matlab engine on python without install matlab?

Tags: python, matlab, module, matlab-engine

I am currently working on the project. For that, I need to run some Matlab functions from my python code.  I don't have MatLab on my Laptop(running on Windows 10). I searched to find a way to install matlab.engine module in python without MatLab on windows.  But unfortunately, I couldn't find out.  Help me!

Comment: Are you talking about [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html)?

Comment: Yes, But to use that technique, I need MatLab installed on my system.  But I didn't have that.  So I am searching for another way to do it.

Comment: So you're asking how to do something that you *know* can't be done?

Comment: Yes, You're correct.  I am asking that Which I knew can't be done.  But that's not mean that can't be done.  suppose any other know how to do it.  that's why I am asking.

Comment: you simply can't. The matlab engine in python will start a Matlab process, but since Matlab is not installed, it can't. No way around it.

Comment: “How can I have a Christmas tree in the house without bringing a Christmas tree into the house?” If you want to use MATLAB, you need to install MATLAB. There is just no way around it.

Comment: Did you tried the Octave (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Octave) instead of MATLAB ?

Comment: You can port your MATLAB functions into Python. Use Numpy and Scipy python packages. This packages are equivalent to MATLAB and also for plotting u can use matplotlib package. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html

Comment: Alternatively you can use oct2Py package in python and run your MATLAB script  https://pypi.org/project/oct2py/